# Plotting vector fields efficiently, using Vtk, avoiding excessive looping

Tags: python, vtk

I'm visualizing some fluid motion. I have a point field and each point is connected to a velocity and acceleration vector. This question is about if my code can be improved, speed-wise, as I'm trying to visualize it as an animation, which takes quite some time for larger fields, which is obvious as to how the code is set up. There is a lot of repetitive work, that in my opinion, should be possible to perform more effectively, I just do not know how to do it.

Working example:

```
import vtk
import numpy as np

renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renderer.SetBackground(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
renderWindow = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renderWindow.AddRenderer(renderer)
renderWindowInteractor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
renderWindowInteractor.SetRenderWindow(renderWindow)

lut = vtk.vtkLookupTable()
lutNum = 2560
lut.SetNumberOfTableValues(lutNum)
ctf = vtk.vtkColorTransferFunction()
ctf.SetColorSpaceToDiverging()
ctf.AddRGBPoint(0.0, 0, 0, 1.0)
ctf.AddRGBPoint(1.0, 1.0, 0, 0)
for ii, xx in enumerate(range(lutNum)):
    ss = float(xx) / float(lutNum)
    cc = ctf.GetColor(ss)
    lut.SetTableValue(ii, cc[0], cc[1], cc[2], 1.0) 
lut.SetRampToLinear()
lut.SetVectorModeToMagnitude()

xx = np.arange(-7, 7, 1)
yy = np.arange(-7, 7, 1)
zz = np.arange(-40, 0, 1)

no_datapts = len(xx) * len(yy) * len(zz)

renderWindowInteractor.Initialize()

points = vtk.vtkPoints()
vel = vtk.vtkFloatArray()
vel.SetNumberOfComponents(3)
vel.SetNumberOfTuples(no_datapts)
acc = vtk.vtkFloatArray()
acc.SetNumberOfComponents(3)
acc.SetNumberOfTuples(no_datapts)
index = 0
for idx, x in enumerate(xx):
    for y in yy:
        for idz, z in enumerate(zz):
            points.InsertPoint(index, x, y, z)
            acc_x = 2 * z + 0.1 * x
            acc_z = 1.2 * z + 0.2 * x
            vel_x = 0.5 * z + 0.7 * x
            vel_z = 0.7 * z + 0.3 * x
            acc.SetTuple3(index, acc_x, 0, acc_z)
            vel.SetTuple3(index, vel_x, 0, vel_z)
            index += 1

grid = vtk.vtkStructuredGrid()
grid.SetPoints(points)
grid.GetPointData().SetVectors(vel)

arrow = vtk.vtkArrowSource()
arrow.SetTipResolution(16)
arrow.SetTipLength(0.3)
arrow.SetTipRadius(0.1)

glyph = vtk.vtkGlyph3D()
glyph.SetInputData(grid)
glyph.SetSourceConnection(arrow.GetOutputPort())
glyph.SetVectorModeToUseVector()
glyph.SetColorModeToColorByVector()
glyph.OrientOn()
glyph.Update()

mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
mapper.SetInputConnection(glyph.GetOutputPort())
mapper.SetLookupTable(lut)
mapper.ScalarVisibilityOn()
mapper.SetScalarModeToUsePointData()
mapper.SetScalarRange(grid.GetPointData().GetVectors().GetRange(-1))

actor = vtk.vtkActor()
actor.SetMapper(mapper)
renderer.AddActor(actor)
renderWindow.Render()
renderWindowInteractor.Start()
```

That should work, I have included some coloring and stuff as well, even though not really necessary for the example but, why not.

The "interesting" thing is that I have a 3D grid, which is basically just a 2D x-z grid that is being represented in multiple y positions.

Hence the question. Is there any way I can avoid this triple loop, by creating my structured grid differently? Do I have to set the points and the tuples individually?

I hope the question is clear, and I will, of course, update the question if you find it unclear and if I find a different solution myself.

I would be most grateful for any help you are able to provide.

Comment: I wonder if you need a structured grid instead a of sparse point cloud.. at the end of the day you may not want to visualize millions of arrows..

Comment: @mmusy You might be right. The need for all these vectors is up for discussion right now, but the first request was that all vectors should be visualized.

Comment: then one thing tha comes up to my mind is using [numpy_support](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/blob/73fb094d17ccdd594a6abf9ff8732149c88dc2e6/Wrapping/Python/vtk/util/numpy_support.py) to set the points, that should be faster than a python loop.